# How to update the cache value when database has change value of same data which is stored in cache

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-4

If i am using laravel 4.2 caching mechanism like bellow.

```
$users = DB::table('users')->remember(10)->get();
```

As i understand cache mechanism query execute one's and story it's value to cache and return data from cache upto 10 minutes.

But my problem is one's query will be executed and data stored it's cache inbetween user table updates it's value then 
how may i check and update cache value so i can get updated data.

Any one have idea any suggestion please let me know...?

Comment: oky then can you just tell me how may i fetch thousands of data from database and page load in sec.

Comment: I have allready applied indexs but still it's load. if you have any other technique then please let me know.

Comment: Once you update the data, update your cache as well. You might want to fire an event for that, I haven't implemented laravel cache so, I'm less sure about that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using a [supported cache driver](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/cache#cache-tags), you can add tags to the caches:

```
$users = DB::table('users')->cacheTags(array('people', 'authors'))->remember(10)->get();
```

Then when the value is updated, you can flush all cached values under your tag. For example, in your User model you could add:

```
public function save(array $options = [])
{
    $result = parent::save($options);

    if ($result) {
        Cache::tags(array('people', 'authors'))->flush();
    }

    return $result;
}
```

Comment: You mean when database update any value at that time I flushed cached data.